# Why the first printf doesn't work while the other two works with the same structure?

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{ 
    struct Numbers
    {
        char cell[21];
        char home[21];
        char business[21];
    };

    // Declare variables here:

    struct Numbers numbers;
    char prompt;

    printf("Do you want to enter a cell phone number? (y or n): ");
    scanf("%s", &prompt);
    if (prompt == 'y' || prompt == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Please enter the contact's cell phone number: ");
        scanf("%s", numbers.cell);
    }

    printf("Do you want to enter a home phone number? (y or n): ");
    scanf("%s", &prompt);
    if (prompt == 'y' || prompt == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Please enter the contact's home phone number: ");
        scanf("%s", numbers.home);
    }

    printf("Do you want to enter a business phone number? (y or n): ");
    scanf("%s", &prompt);
    if (prompt == 'y' || prompt == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Please enter the contact's business phone number: ");
        scanf("%s", numbers.business);
    }

    printf("\n");

    printf("Phone Numbers:");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Cell phone number: %s", numbers.cell);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Home phone number: %s", numbers.home);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Business phone number: %s", numbers.business);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Structure test for Name, Address, and Numbers Done!");

    return 0;
}
```

Here is how the output looks like:
[image]

The cell phone number is empty while home phone and business phone work.
Once I made a mistake input as y->12345->y->12345->y12345->12345, then all 3 numbers show correctly. I can't find what's the problem.

Result for mistaken input:
[image]

Comment: Please do not post images when you can copy and past the text

Comment: `scanf("%s", &prompt);` -> This is wrong - Where is it going to put the null character to mark the end of the string

Comment: The problem with the logic is thus - if they do not wish to will in the phone number are you filling in with a "null"

Comment: why u r using `%s` while hiving `prompt` as `char`..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems with printout comes from overwriting the first member of the structure.

The byte sequence `{'y', '\0'}` is being written to the single-byte `prompt` *and* what follows, which is almost certainly the first byte of `numbers`. This is therefore setting the first character of the `cell` field to `'\0'`, making it an empty string.

If you want to use string formatting `"%s"` in `scanf("%s", &prompt);` the `prompt` has to be as string type. Char variable is unable to hold character plus null string terminator read by your `scanf`.

The more natural and typical approach is to use `" %c"` for the character read. Both ways are presented.

Note 1:
The `%c` conversion specifier won't automatically skip any leading whitespace, so if there's a stray newline in the input stream (from a previous entry, for example) the scanf call will consume it immediately.

One way around the problem is to put a blank space before the conversion specifier in the format string:

```
scanf(" %c", &c);
```

Note 2: Typically we declare structures before `main` to give them global scope in the file.

Note 3:  Also, if you declare `numbers` as a local struct variable then all of the struct members are undefined. In case of user skipping filling the number you may get a garbage printout for that field. You are obligated to initialize those members yourself.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

struct Numbers
{
    char cell[21];
    char home[21];
    char business[21];
};

int main (void)
{
    // Declare variables here:

    char prompt[10];
    char prompt1;

    struct Numbers numbers;

    numbers.cell[0] = '\0';
    numbers.home[0] = '\0';
    numbers.business[0] = '\0';

    printf("Do you want to enter a cell phone number? (y or n):\n");
    scanf(" %c", &prompt1);

    if (prompt1 == 'y' || prompt1 == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Please enter the contact's cell phone number:\n");
        scanf("%s", numbers.cell);
    }

    printf("Do you want to enter a home phone number? (y or n):\n");
    scanf(" %c", &prompt1);
    if (prompt1 == 'y' || prompt1 == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Please enter the contact's home phone number:\n");
        scanf("%s", numbers.home);
    }

    printf("Do you want to enter a business phone number? (y or n):\n");
    scanf("%s", &prompt);
    if (*prompt == 'y' || *prompt == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Please enter the contact's business phone number:\n");
        scanf("%s", numbers.business);
    }

    printf("\n");

    printf("Phone Numbers:");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Cell phone number: %s", numbers.cell);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Home phone number: %s", numbers.home);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Business phone number: %s", numbers.business);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Structure test for Name, Address, and Numbers Done!");

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Do you want to enter a cell phone number? (y or n):                                                                                           
y                                                                                                                                             
Please enter the contact's cell phone number:                                                                                                 
123                                                                                                                                           
Do you want to enter a home phone number? (y or n):                                                                                           
y                                                                                                                                             
Please enter the contact's home phone number:                                                                                                 
456                                                                                                                                           
Do you want to enter a business phone number? (y or n):                                                                                       
y                                                                                                                                             
Please enter the contact's business phone number:                                                                                             
789                                                                                                                                           

Phone Numbers:                                                                                                                                
Cell phone number: 123                                                                                                                        
Home phone number: 456                                                                                                                        
Business phone number: 789                                                                                                                    
Structure test for Name, Address, and Numbers Done!
```

Comment: Instead of `char prompt[10];` and `scanf("%s", &prompt);`, we can do `char prompt;` and `scanf("%c", &prompt)`.

Comment: @H.S. Thank you for your comment! Of course we can! I just wanted to reuse `%s`. Your proposal is more natural though. Thanks!

Comment: It might be worth mentioning in more detail *why* what's happening is happening. In other words, the byte sequence `{'y', '\0'}` is being written to the single-byte prompt *and* what follows, which is almost certainly the first byte of `numbers`. This is setting the `cell` field first character to `\0`, making it an empty string.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thank you!  This is great comment!  I will include it in the answer.